# python vba xlwings: import more than one python script

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to import multiple python scripts so that they can be run from excel using excelwings.  The code below, in VBA, only

```
Sub do_ranking()
    RunPython ("import RankandBacktest, factors; RankandBacktest.do_ranker()")
End Sub
```

I would then like to access the functions contained within script 'factors.py' from 'RankandBacktest.py'.

Unfortunately, it appears that xlwings can only import one script.

Comment: Have you tried importing any needed functions from `factors.py` into `RankandBacktest.py` and using them? I don't think it's necessary to import both.

Comment: Yes, and that does work.  But the problem is that those functions are used by other code and get changed.  I'd rather not have to keep copying the latest versions across into this file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'used by other code and get changed'? Are you using similar naming conventions between scripts? Can you add to your question a snippet of how you are importing between the two?

Comment: I mean that I have 4 scripts of functions that are called by other python code.  I could just put all the functions into one script and then just edit the functions within that large, unwieldy script from now on.  But it would be much neater to have separate scripts and only import what is actually being used into xlwings.  It isn't a major issue to be honest, I just wondered how one can do it with xlwings as I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: 'it would be much neater to have separate scripts and only import what is actually being used into xlwings'... Just do this into whatever script you are importing into xlwings... I'm sure this is a simple issue, however you;re giving me little to nothing to go off of.